# Click event function not working in PyQT6 when added dynamically

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm creating a bunch of QPushButton's in PyQt6 dynamically in a loop. They all use the same target function and the only difference between them is one argument they are receiving, but for some reason, when i assign them dynamically, the all get the arg of the last one assigned.

Doing this:

```
for i in range(n):
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda: click_event(i))
```

All events get assigned like this, with n as the argument:

```
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: click_event(n))
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: click_event(n))
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: click_event(n))
...
```

But if i assign them "manually":

```
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: click_event(0))
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: click_event(1))
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: click_event(2))
...
```

They work flawless..

Any idea what could it be?

Comment: `btn.clicked.connect(lambda _, i=i: click_event(i))`

Comment: Well, you're very welcome... And you can [get me that beer](//stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/?tab=profile) too whenever you want! ;-)